# Why doesn't jQuery .toggle() work properly?

Tags: jquery

I am wrapping up a mobile site and have added a navigation section that should toggle in and out when clicking on the list icon in the header. For testing purposes I have it showing right now, but whether it is showing or not, the toggle function is not working. Here is the page: sunsetwesterngardencollection.com/mobile/ (it looks better small).

Here is the html for the trigger:

```
<header>
    <h1><a href="{site_url}mobile/"><img src="{site_url}/images-mobile/logo-sunset.png" alt="Sunset Western Garden Collection"></a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="toggle" href="#"><img src="{site_url}/images-mobile/icon_main-menu.png" alt="main menu"></a></li>
        <li><a href="{site_url}mobile/search"><img src="{site_url}/images-mobile/icon_search.png" alt="search sunset"></a></li>
        <li><a href="{site_url}mobile/find-retailer"><img src="{site_url}/images-mobile/icon_finder.png" alt="retail locator"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</header>
```

Here is the html for the div that should toggle in and out:

```
<div id="quick-nav">
        <ul id="quick">
                <li><a href="{site_url}mobile/"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{site_url}mobile/the-collection"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>The Collection</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{site_url}mobile/find-retailer"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>Where to Buy</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{site_url}mobile/blog"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>Our Blog</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/SunsetWesternGardenCollection"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>Follow us on Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/SunsetPlants"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>Follow us on Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{site_url}index2/"><img src="/images-mobile/bg_quick-nav.png" alt="home" /><span>Go to Full Site</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!--end #quick-nav-->
```

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("a#toggle").click(function () {
$("#quick-nav").toggle("slow");
});

</script>
```

I have tested this in isolation and it works properly, but on this page it does not. I need another pair of eyes to help identify the problem so I can fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your event binding under document.ready. Chances are that your event binding is getting executed before the document is loaded or before the element exist

```
$(function(){
   $("a#toggle").click(function () {
    $("#quick-nav").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi PSL, yes that solved the problem. Thanks. Credit coming in 11 minutes.